# Итератор для ветора в векторе

Tags: c++, qt

Имеем вектор `vector<vector<string>> all;`
в него пихем

```
vector<string> a = {"+","Znak orifmeticheskoy operacii",g};
         all.push_back(a);
```

Используя такой итератор как мне обращаться к столбцам конкретной строки?
нужно реализовать поиск по первому столбцу.

```
vector<vector<string>>::iterator it;
for (it=all.begin();it!=all.end();it++){
    std::cout<<&it <<" ";}
```

И как сделать вывод в нормальном формате(string) а не в &it(результат 0x8ec880)?
и все это в QT.

Comment: Итератор - это указатель, а вы выводите адрес указателя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Используя такой итератор как мне обращаться к столбцам конкретной строки?

```
for (auto it : all) {
    const auto& nested_vector = *it;
    for (auto it_n : nested_vector) {
        // do smth
    } 
    // UPD: const auto elm = nested_vector[i];
}
```

Еще пример:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using col_t = std::string;
using row_t = std::vector<col_t>;
using mrx_t = std::vector<row_t>;

int main() {
    const mrx_t mrx = {
        { "+", "add", "..." },
        { "-", "sub", "..." },
        { "*", "mul", "..." },
        { "/", "div", "..." }
    };


    for (mrx_t::size_type i = 0; i < mrx.size(); ++i) {
        const row_t& row = mrx[i];
        for (row_t::size_type j = 0; j < row.size(); ++j) {
            if (i > 0 && mrx[i - 1][0] == "+" && i <= mrx.size() - 1 && mrx[i + 1][0] == "*") {
                assert(mrx[i][0] == "-");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как таким образом проверить значения предшествующего элемента и значение последующего? Это же просто перебор от начало до конце без возможности перемещения?

Comment: @ВикторЯковлев, не совсем Вас понял, о каком перемещении идет речь. Что касается обращения к элементу по индексу - используйте оператор [] вместо моего вложенного цикла. Сейчас обновлю пример.

Comment: for(auto u:all){
    if(u[0].find('+')==false){//поиск по первому столбцу    
    } в строке 3 столбца необходимо проверять значение 1 столбца в предшествующей и последующей строках

Comment: @ВикторЯковлев, не используйте модный loop, используйте цикл for с индексами. Я не вижу здесь никакой сложности.

Comment: используя for (it=all.begin();it!=all.end();it++) или такой for(int i=0;i<all.size();i++) как мне обратиться к элементам 1 столбца?

Comment: @ВикторЯковлев, у Вас нет элементов первого столбца. Вообще, нет самих столбцов. У Вас есть только строки. Вы же используете ветктор, а не двумерный массив.

Comment: Я использую вектор вектора строк и модным loop-ом у меня получается брать значение 1 столбца(строки) из первой строки(auto u:all u[0]-это не первая строка ветора all  а первый элемент этой строки), но не получается перемещаться по строкам. а обычным for-ом получаю только строки целиком а к элеметам строки нет доступа.

Comment: @ВикторЯковлев, Давайте определимся с терминологией. Я использовал следующую: std::vector<string> - строка, std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> - массив строк. Под i столбцом я понимал следующее: из каждой строки берем i-тый элемент, их совокупность - столбец. Все верно?

Comment: @ВикторЯковлев, обновил пример.

Comment: Спасибо. Сам бы не догадался разделить на части свою запись vector<vector<string>>.

Comment: @ВикторЯковлев, рад помочь!

Answer (score 0):

cout не умеет выводить vector. Нужно вывести первый элемент вектора.

```
vector<vector<string>>::iterator it;
for (it=all.begin();it!=all.end();it++){
    std::cout << it[0] << " ";
}
```

В вашем случае стоит рассмотреть использования QMap т.к. vector не очень подходит, если нужно производить по нему поиск.

```
QMap<QString, QStringList> all;
QStringList a;

a.append("Znak orifmeticheskoy operacii");
a.append(g);

all["+"] = a;

...

if (all.contains("+")){
    cout << all["+"].join(" ").toStdString;
}
```

Comment: Как таким образом проверить значения предшествующего элемента и значение последующего? т.е. если в третьей строке + то необходимо знать что по бокам(2,4 строки).

Comment: Если использовать QMap никак. Тогда можно использовать QList<QStringList>. Придется делать перебор элементов QList и проверять значение QStringList[0].